# How to connect to multiple database on different docker containers from a Windows host without publishing the ports?

Tags: docker

I have multiple docker stacks for different web application running on the same machine.
I'm already using nginx-proxy to access each app with its own host name.
This spares me from publishing a different http port for each app.

Is there any way of doing something similar with other services, like databases?
I'd like to be able to connect to each database with my tools (like Mysql Workbench and such) without explicitly publishing a different port for each database.

EDIT: the MacVlan network driver seems to be an option on a Linux host, but it's not available on Windows.

Comment: You can have as many containers you want listening on their `3306` port (for MySQL for example). There is no restriction. But if you decide to `publish` one of these ports to the `3306` port of the host, this binding can be done only for one container.

Comment: @tgogos sorry, 'exposing' wasn't the right term, I was thinking about publishing.
nginx-proxy already requires exposing the http ports of the different containers.

Comment: So, you want a reverse proxy, but for mysql databases. I haven't heard of such tools.

Comment: Docker has some networking differences depending on the platform you are working on (Windows, Linux, MacOS). For my case (Linux), I can use the Workbench app installed on the host and point directly to `any_mysql_container_ip:3306`.

Comment: But what IP do you use for that? Do your containers have a public IP accessible from the LAN?

Comment: Ok, maybe what I need is the MacVlan network driver.

Comment: Ah, but that only works for Linux hosts. I'm on Windows. Bummer.

Comment: Not sure what 'publish a port' means to you, but if you want to have a single "ip_address:port" TCP listener on which you access multiple databases, in the same way as you can have a single TCP listener that answers to multiple host names on the same IP address (e.g., "http://host1:80", "http://host2:80", etc.) and shows you **different** web sites depending on the hostname: that is NOT possible. The HTTP protocol allows this because the host name is sent in the request headers, so a proxy like NGINX can dispatch by it. There's no such thing in the SQL protocol.

Comment: "SQL protocol"? Aren't SQL queries sent through TCP? (or other protocols, or unix sockets...)